# How to create multiple dropdown menus with MaterializeCSS?

Tags: javascript, materialize

How can I generate n dropdown menus using MaterializeCSS and JavaScript? I tried creating one dropdown structure and having all buttons trigger that one dropdown but nothing happens when I click on any of the buttons.

```html
<div id="button-container">
</div>

<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
 </ul>
```

```js
var htmlStr = ''
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    htmlStr += `
        <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>
    `
}
$(#button-container).html(htmlStr)
```

Comment: Please paste your code for others to help you. Otherwise, people will point you to docs or tutorials

Comment: @adlopez15 I just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and I think the problem is you haven't initialized the dropdown. You can do it using :

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
```

Have a look at [Materialize Doc - Dropdown Initialization](https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html#initialization)

There is a working code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/7ua4pb6z/16/).

Answer (score 0):

Data-target should be unique, so this line repeated 100 times is a problem:

```
<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>
```

Non unique data-targets will prevent any of the dropdown triggers from working.

As a rule, dropdown trigger and targets should come in unique pairs.